# What does sample independence mean in Item Response Theory (IRT)

Tags: item-response-theory

I keep reading that (at least the difficulty parameters of) an IRT model is sample independent. I find it difficult to get my head around this concept.

- Surely there must be limits to this statement. Under what conditions/assumptions is an IRT model sample independent?
- Does this mean that if I build a model from a sample (eg. a large, but biased sample, where strong ability candidates are greatly over represented) the mean $\theta$ of the sample can be significantly different from 0?

I am generating here a model from a skewed sample. I expected the mean of the resulting $\theta$s to be different from 0, but it isn't.

```
nPerson=1000

library(sn)
sample<-rsn(n=nPerson, xi=0, omega=1, alpha=1)

library(psych)
describe(sample)

library(mirtCAT)
nitems <- 20
a1 <- rlnorm(nitems, .2,.2)
d <- rnorm(nitems)
pars <- data.frame(a1=a1, d=d)
obj <- generate.mirt_object(pars, '2PL')

df<-NULL
for(i in 1:nPerson) {
  resp<-generate_pattern(obj, sample[i])
  rbind(df,data.frame(resp))->df
}

fit <- mirt(df, 1)
scores<-fscores(fit, response.pattern = df)
scores<-as.data.frame(scores)

mean(scores$F1)
```

Comment: It's certainly true that the mean $\theta$ can be different from zero (e.g., in the Rasch model $b$ is typically constrained to have a mean of zero, so a sample containing too many high skilled people may have a mean $\theta>0$), but I'm not sure how accurate it is to say that this is a consequence of sample independence

Comment: On the subject of the Rasch model, it's worth pointing out that it's only the 1 parameter IRT model (i.e. Rasch) that has parameters which are sample independent. Obviously this speaks to your first question.